# startActivity() returns NPE after load adView mob

Tags: android, admob

My app uses navigation drawer. My app will crash with the following error:

```
08-30 16:44:30.079  22176-22176/com.imincode.meniti W/System.err﹕ java.lang.NullPointerException
08-30 16:44:30.089  22176-22176/com.imincode.meniti W/System.err﹕ at com.imincode.meniti.MenuGoals$2$1.onClick(MenuGoals.java:127)
08-30 16:44:30.089  22176-22176/com.imincode.meniti W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:166)
08-30 16:44:30.089  22176-22176/com.imincode.meniti W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-30 16:44:30.089  22176-22176/com.imincode.meniti W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
```

Line 127 is displayed below

```
@Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater)
    {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
MenuItem tbAddItem = menu.findItem(R.id.tbAddItem);
        tbAddItem.setVisible(true);
    tbAddItem.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem menuItem) {
                    new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                            .setTitle(getContext().getString(R.string.download_paid_title))
                            .setMessage(getContext().getString(R.string.download_paid_content))
                            .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                            .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

    Uri uri = Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.imincode.menitiplus");
    Intent goToMarket = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
    goToMarket.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK);
    try {
        startActivity(goToMarket);  //line 127
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
       getActivity().startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + getActivity().getPackageName())));
     }  }
                        })
                        .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, null).show();
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Take note that the error will be thrown ONLY WHEN the condition below is met:

1. Firstly, load a fragment with admob
2. From the navigation drawer, load another fragment. This fragment doesn't have any admob.
3. This fragment has a button to load the Play Store, as displayed above.
4. Clicking on the button will throw the error mentioned above.
5. If I don't use AlertDialog (means just create a button on the view and click on it), I can open Play Store without any problem. So I think AlertDialog is one of the culprit.

Take note that the Play Store can be launched without any problem or error, if I did NOT load a fragment with admob prior on opening the fragment which has a button to load the Play Store (and eventualy clicking on the button to load Play Store).

Btw here's the code to load adMob on the other fragment.

```
AdView mAdView = (AdView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
        mAdView.destroy();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several hours of debugging, found out that just by changing return false to return true at the AlertDialog fixes the problem. Everything is working fine now.

Basically here's the new code:

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext())
                    .setTitle(getContext().getString(R.string.download_paid_title))
                    .setMessage(getContext().getString(R.string.download_paid_content))
                    .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                    .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

                            Uri uri = Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.imincode.menitiplus");
                            Intent goToMarket = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
                            goToMarket.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK);
                            try {
                                startActivity(goToMarket);
                            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                                startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + getActivity().getPackageName())));
                            }

                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, null).show();
            return true;
```

As you can see, the last return is changed from false to true. Not sure why this works though.